# Docker User-defined Network - Inter-Container Communication via Container Host Name

Tags: docker, spring-boot, activemq-classic

***Issue*** - Spring-Boot Message Listener Docker Container is failing to connect to ActiveMQ Docker Container within the same Docker User-defined Network

CONFIGURE Spring-Boot Message Listener to check for "**activemq.hostname**"

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" 
class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
<property name="brokerURL" value="failover:
(tcp://${activemq.hostname:0.0.0.0}:61616)?randomize=false" />
</bean>
```

CREATE Docker File for Spring-Boot Message Listener - sets hostname for message broker to **event-broker**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 9001
RUN mkdir /app/
COPY target/event-ingestion-router-1.0.2.jar /app/
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Dactivemq.hostname='event-broker' -jar 
/app/event-ingestion-router-1.0.2.jar
```

CREATE Docker Network

```
docker network create --driver=bridge messaging-network
```

CREATE ActiveMQ Broker running on "messaging-network" with hostname **event-broker**

```
docker run -d -p 61616:61616 -p 8161:8161 --net=messaging-network \
  --hostname event-broker --name event-broker rmohr/activemq:5.14.3-alpine
```

CREATE Spring-Boot Message Listener on "messaging-network" - connecting to **event-broker**

```
docker run -d -p 9001:9001 -e JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx256m -Xms128m' \
  --net=messaging-network --name event-ingestion event-ingestion:latest
```

VIEW Network messaging-network

```
"Containers": {
"28707ba65bb2d05e1eed38d0f76587129668b61275a6d076674290f9f85d0b36": {
"Name": "event-broker",
"EndpointID": 
"98bc2749fee0442c980347ecbde8002a8462239cb4e0e8d5e01ea2655ec4c722",
"MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
"IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
"IPv6Address": ""
},
"48d049f054baac3183407b8ee320dd27be8645c026ec3502e83d4bc7502ccf01": {
"Name": "event-ingestion",
"EndpointID": 
"6c908d2cf1c922c7b2baa0bb399d1a456b99be542d45ae1559e6cc8f6b9ac68b",
"MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
"IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
"IPv6Address": ""
}
}
```

But unable to have message listener connect to message broker. Somehow hostname of message broker container is not resolving.

Note trying to accomplish this task without using *deprecated* Links. Also would like to see if this is possible without Compose (for now).

Comment: Anything possible *with* compose is also possible *without* compose.  Docker-compose doesn't add any features to Docker, it just makes things (much) easier to manage.

Comment: In what way are things failing? Are you explicitly getting a "no such host" sort of error, or some other behavior? For what it's worth, I can't replicate your problem: if I start an `alpine` container with same arguments as you `event-broker` and a second matching the args for your `invent-ingestion` container, everything works fine. The `event-ingestion` container can contact `event-broker` by name.

Comment: E.g., https://asciinema.org/a/BkSo74ukf1NjaXmqP9BR3FeXc

Comment: Thank you both for such quick responses. You are right, it does connect "Successfully connected to tcp://event-broker:61616" but I guess the real issue is why the camel route does not start " Total 0 routes, of which 0 are started." in Docker. But if I run the same app outside of docker the routes start-up connected to Docker Event-Broker....curiouser and curiouser

Comment: Have you checked the spring boot logs to see what the camel context is saying? Also, have you tried to login to the docker container and manually connect to the active mq broker ?

Comment: I previously changed log level to debug and saw no errors or warnings regarding the camel context. To sanity check, I deployed this solution with just a Spring Message Listener (no Camel) and everything worked fine. The Spring-Boot App connected to ActiveMQ (both on the messaging-network). The mystery is why the Apache Camel ActiveMQ Component does not seem to work in Docker. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

The root cause was using an old package scanning technique for Camel Routes, scanning worked locally but failed when deployed to Docker. So I upgraded to using spring-boot camel

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And annotated my Route Builder with @Component:

```
@Component
public class EventIngestionRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder implements 
RoutesBuilder {
...
```

Using this approach routes were discovered both locally and when deployed via Docker.

```
03:02:41.118 | [ActiveMQ Task-1] | INFO | FailoverTransport | 
Successfully connected to tcp://event-broker:61616

03:02:41.146 | [main] | INFO | SpringCamelContext | Route: route1 
started and consuming from: activemq://event.ingestion

03:02:41.146 | [main] | INFO | SpringCamelContext | Total 1 routes, of 
which 1 are started.
```